# MetisMenu Third Level Always Collapse

Tags: javascript, menu, metis

I'm using MetisMenu, when I have a link on a third layer menu item the parent menu items all collapse once the link has been clicked.

The second level menu itme links work correctly.

My sample code is here:

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">

<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">

        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                <li><a href="/admin/index"> Works Correctly!</a></li>                   
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                        <li><a href="/admin/layers/index"> DOES NOT WORK - ALWAYS COLLPOASE PARENTS</a></li>          
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>       

    </ul>

</div>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue and similar solution to the one above, only adding adding class `active` to all nested `<li>`.  This allows the chevron-right to be a chevron-down.

```
var url = window.location;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
});

if (element) {
    element.addClass('active').parents('#side-menu ul').addClass('in');
    element.parents('#side-menu li').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I think it works, I also added an extra collapse in the third level. It prevents the complex flickering. I think the Metis menu is need more work on this.  <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">

Comment: Nice!  Just merged that into my project.

Answer (score 0):

We recently encountered this problem, a lot of debugging showed, that the problem was with how sb-admin marked html elements as active (specifically, "li" tags).

The file in question is sb-admin-2.js. Down at the bottom it has the following bit of code:

```
var url = window.location;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
}
```

First, sb-admin calculates the depth level of your URL and uses this number to index child elements. It then uses this number to iterate through the particular branch of the DOM tree bottom-to-top. It then marks these elements as "active".

In our case the URL wouldn't change, but the number of elements would (for three-levels deep structure it would be 3, but the index remained 2). So, the third and second level elements would become active, but everything else is marked passive, so the top element would collapse, hiding the whole sub-menu.

This is how we fixed it (I'm not a JS guy, so I don't know how good this solution is, but it works):

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
}).addClass('active').parents('#side-menu ul').addClass('in');
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location;
// var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
//     return this.href == url;
// }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active').parent();

//    while (true) {
//    if (element.is('li')) {
//           element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent();
//        } else {
//            break;
//        }
//   }
```

This will do the trick guys[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N54N1.jpg)